# Bind variables with identical names

Tags: r

Assume that I have the following 100 variables that **already have assigned values**. This means, I am **loading** them.

Their assigned *names* are identical, except for the ending, they end in different numbers:

i.e. D1=23, D2=45,...,D100=67

Is there a quick and efficient way to bind them, preferably as rows. Obviously I could:

```
D_ALL<-rbind(D1,D2,..,D100)
```

But is there a quicker way to handle this?

For instance, a loop such as:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=100, by=1))
{
D[i]<-D$i
 }
```

This sort of loop is not going to work in R (it would in STATA with the dollar `$` sign).

I am wondering if there is a solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Just do `library(data.table);rbindlist(mget(paste0("D", 1:100)))` or with `base R` `do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("D", 1:100)))`

Comment: Thank you so much! It was the "do.call" function that I was unaware of.